# FormData Axios Post: Why is the Server Receiving an Empty Body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Problem sending data from client to server with Axios and FormData. Despite correctly configuring the body-parser middleware on the server to parse form data, the request body on the server is arriving empty (req.body is null or does not contain the expected data).

Verified body-parser setup on server. Ensured FormData field names match.

**CLIENT**

```
const url = `${location.origin}/agregar/`;

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("urlProyect", btneliminar.dataset.proyectoUrl);
formdata.append("tarea", nuevaTarea.value);

axios.post(url, formdata);
```

**SERVER**

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('./config/db');
require('./models/Proyectos');
require('./models/Tareas');

db.sync()
  .then(()=>{console.log('its ok')})
  .catch((error => {console.log('oh no!')}))

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/', routes());

app.listen(3000);
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
exports.agregarTarea = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // return {}
}
```

Comment: I want to clean the data with express-validator

router.post('/agregar', tasksController.addTask);

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on client side, you must provide in your axios request headers `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, in order to let server to know that you are sending body
`{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }`